# Question how to validate element after Guice upgrade to 4.2

Tags: java, guice

I had to upgrade a few libraries in an existing project, and one was Guice, from 4.1 to 4.2
The method below needs some modification, and I am not sure on how to achieve this:

```
final Annotation annotation = binding.getKey().getAnnotation();
return annotation instanceof Element && ((Element)annotation).type() == MULTIBINDER
```

Note MULTIBINDER was initially imported as below:

```
import static com.google.inject.multibindings.Element.Type.MULTIBINDER
```

But on Guice 4.2, it seems to be in an internal package?

Any assistance would be appreciated. Tks!

Comment: You're showing way too few code for us to understand the intent of the method. Why was the returned boolean used? Why is it useful? If we know the goal, we can probably show alternatives. At this point, we can only guess. Anyways, this kind of refactoring is what happens when people use explicitly internal classes. the class `com.google.inject.multibindings.Element` was marked as [package-private in 4.1](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/4.1/extensions/multibindings/src/com/google/inject/multibindings/Element.java) so I don't get how you could even import it.

Comment: Hi @OlivierGrégoire, tks for your comment. 
With that, I could realise the class was using same package as Element. As it changed its package, I had to change the package of the class as well.  Not happy with that approach, as it is internal package now, but will keep that to continue my POC and will consider the results later and how to fix it.
Tks again!